# Apache Archiva set admin account password

Tags: apache, archiva

I have only ssh access to machine where I need to setup the Archiva. So i wonder have can I create a admin account and set a password to that account.

I found in Archiva API /userService/createAdminUser but still I don't understand how to add a password to the user that will be created by this API request.

Or maybe you can help me with another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user format is defined here: http://archiva.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/rest-docs-redback-rest-api/el_ns0_user.html (the api accept both json and xml)

NOTE: you won't be able to use this api#method if the admin user already exists!